ckan session variable to monitor activity
I am currently working on ckan and would like to monitor the upload progress and refresh the access_token whenever needed. I have implemented some login and session management in ckan and would need to refresh the access token when there is upload still happening in the background.
Is there any library I can use to store some value and it can be used in the entire session? It won't clear off when the page is reload?
I have tried using app_globals (not sure if I should use it) and the values will be removed when the page is refresh. Is there any other ways that I can do it?
